# Entity Framework - How to add entities referencing each other without knowing primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, insert

I am very new to Entity Framework, so apologies if its a very bad question, but I could not find a solution that makes sense to me. Although my problem is complex, I will try to simplify it. Let's say I have two models Company and CompanyAddress.

```
+--------------------Company---------------------------------------+
| int CompanyId
| string CompanyName
|
| virtual <ICollection>CompanyAddress address // Navigation Property
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And,

```
+--------------------CompanyAddress---------------------------+
| int CompanyAddressId
| string Address
|
| int CompanyAddressId           // Foreign Key to Address Table
| virtual CompanyAddress address // Related Navigation Property
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As it can be seen Company entity can have more than one CompanyAddress. In my ASP.NET MVC project I have also ViewModel.

```
+--------------------CompanyCreateViewModel----------------+
| Company company
| CompanyAddress address
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

These two properties are filled on view and passed to controller without problems. Problem for me starts now. How should I insert these two entities ?

Let's say I insert Company entity first than grab its primaryKey with select statement and assign this value to CompanyAddress's foreign key and insert it. However, this does not make sense to me, since I need to make another request for primary key.

How should I insert my entities, what is the best approach ? Sorry for long question, and thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this statement you made "However, this does not make sense to me, since I need to make another request for primary key. "  - why do you think you need to make another request for the same primary key?  Once you call SaveChanges() for the Company, you have the PrimaryKey in that object.  Assign it to the foreign key for CompanyAddress and call SaveChanges() again.

Comment: Hmm, did not know that. As i said i am very new to orm and ef things. Anyways that solved my problem :) please write as answer so i can accept it. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you call SaveChanges() for the Company, you have the PrimaryKey in that object. Assign it to the foreign key for CompanyAddress and call SaveChanges() again.

Comment: btw, is this a good approach? I was thinking of assigning address to company via navigation property, then inserting company and address entity together. Instead of inserting company first followed by address ?

Comment: IF you have your database set up properly, that works, too.  And that is one step, not two.  Which, is more efficient :)